# Spring, No message found under code 'error.action.empty' for locale 'pl_PL'

Tags: spring, properties, locale, message

I am new to Spring. I tried to find the answer to my question but none of the answers fixed my problem. It's simple - Spring cant find my messages.properties.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/classes/messages" />
</bean>
```

I also tried other configurations for path like:
classpath:messages, messages, classes/messages. None of this worked for me. 
My messages path is: Project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties
I also have messages_pl.properties and messages_pl_PL.properties there.

Comment: Are you able to get the messages from other properties files?

Comment: I already fixed the problem. The value of basename should be just "messages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

It looks like this is the right answer.